# Why is creating an array in a outer parameterized class with a component type being an inner class considered "Generic array creation"?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
public class A<T> {
    B[] bs = new B[5];

    private class B {

    }
}
```

I receive a compile-time error saying that `new B[5]` is generic array creation. I did not expect this because:

1. B itself is not parametrized.
2. B is not a type parameter of A.

With these reasons in mind, why is `new B[5]` still considered generic array creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the only way to create an instance of `B` (since it is an inner class) is with an instance of a parameterized `A`. Simple fix, change

```
private class B
```

to

```
private static class B
```

Comment: @Ivan Please don't encourage the use of [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since `B` is an non-static inner class of `A`, inside the scope of `A`, the unqualified name `B` implies `A<T>.B`, and this is a parameterized type (even though `B` doesn't look parameterized). (This makes sense since non-static inner classes contain a reference to an outer class instance; since this reference to the outer class instance is parameterized, the inner class instance must also be parameterized, so the inner class instance "inherits" the outer class type parameter.) You cannot create an array of a parameterized type in an array creation expression, so you cannot do `new B[5]` (because it implicitly means `new A<T>.B[5]`).

You can instead create an array of the raw type. But remember that `B` itself is a parameterized type and not a raw type. To get the raw type, you must explicitly qualify it with the raw outer class type:

```
B[] bs = new A.B[5];
```

Or you can create an array of the wildcard-parameterized type:

```
B[] bs = (B[])new A<?>.B[5];
```

In both cases, you will get an unchecked warning, which is always unavoidable in Java if you want to get a variable of a type "array of parameterized type", like `B[]`.